# Odds of winning a "pick a number between a and b" style game

Tags: probability

Say someone tells you to choose a number between 1 and 10,000, and that a random number will be generated within that range, and whoever is closest to that number wins. If the number that is generated is truly random, does every number between 1 and 10,000 have an equal chance of resulting in a win?

Intuitively, if there are 10,000 numbers to choose from, and 10,000 players who all choose a different number, the answer is "yes, each number is equally likely to win". However, if there are not 10,000 players, I think choosing a number that casts the largest "net" around the numbers around it is the best way to win.

For example, if three players choose a number between 1 and 10: Player 1 chooses "1", and Player 2 chooses "10", so then Player 3 should choose "5", because then they are closest to 4, 5, and 6, whereas Player 1 is only closest to 1 and 2, and Player 2 is only closest to 9 and 10.

Comment: Do they also choose a random number (in addition to the random generated number)?

Comment: @NickGuerrero No, the players would not choose randomly, and we'll also assume that no two players will choose the same number and that there will never be more players than there are numbers to choose from.

Comment: So, since players can't pick the same number, that can affect how the other players act.  Are you familiar with the game show price is right?  Rather than making realistic bids, one of the players may choose to bid 1 dollar, and if another player follows, that player could bid two dollars, completely ruining that earlier player's chances of winning.  Same here.  The later players, having more information, can capitalize on that.

Comment: Had it been a two player game, the correct move by the first player would have been to pick the middle number, the second player would then pick the number one greater or one less than the first player, resulting in a win for the first player if the generated number "lied on his side" of the numberline.  If the first player followed this strategy in a three player game however, that ruins his chances as the second and third players could surround his, resulting in him winning only on an exact match, the second and third players winning if the number landed on "their side" respectively.

Comment: @JMoravitz So if I'm understanding you correctly, while the probability of each number being the randomly generated winning number doesn't change, the probability of winning with any one number changes as players make their picks?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Actually determining what choice to make for each player to maximize their respective chances of winning would fall under the label of "Game Theory."  There is the issue of whether or not certain players choose to collude as well.  [Here are some partial results](https://srcole.github.io/2015/06/14/guess/).